# Gradle Jar task ignore destinationDir in doLast

Tags: gradle, jar, task

I need do Jar task during execution phase of build.
I tried

```
task ("createJar", type: Jar, dependsOn: "some_task") {
  doLast{
    println ("default destinationDir " + destinationDir)
    destinationDir file("some_location")
    println ("destinationDir after change" + destinationDir)
    from "some_dir"
  }
}
```

Logger shows that value of destinationDir has been changed. But when I run script it creates Jar in default location instead of "some_location".

If I remove "doLast" then task works during configuration phase and ignore dependsOn value that doesn't fit my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not change the configuration in the execution phase. This will work against the up-to-date check and your task might execute when it would not be necessary or even worse do not execute when it would be necessary. Unless you completely disable the up-to-date check for this task, but then you disable one of the big strenghts of Gradle.

Do not do the `doLast`, it works correctly. The task is **not** run during configuration phase as you stated. Just your `println` statements are run during the configuration phase as they are in the configuration block then. The actual task execution will happen after the dependency you defined.

**PS:** Of course you would have to set the configuration in `doFirst { }`, not `doLast { }`. As the name suggests, `doLast { }` is executed **after** all already existing task actions, `doFirst { }` **before**. But please don't do it, it is most probably not the right thing to do.